# Why XSD sequence shows as ambiguous

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'd like to have a xsd to valide an xml containing file elements, but in xsd have error

> Warning   1   Wildcard '##any' allows element 'http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema:Attachments', and causes the content model to become ambiguous. A content model must be formed such that during validation of an element information item sequence, the particle contained directly, indirectly or implicitly therein with which to attempt to validate each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.  ECEP_Letter.xsd 204 18

Please help me

This is my xsd:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema" xmlns:irecetns="http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema" xmlns="http://www.irica.com/ECEP/1383-12/SendSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified" version="1.01">
<xs:element name="Letter">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Protocol" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Software" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="SoftwareDeveloper" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="Version" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xs:attribute name="GUID" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Sender" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Organization" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Department" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Position" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Receiver" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Organization" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Department" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Position" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="ReceiveType" type="irecetns:ReceiveType" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="OtherReceivers" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="OtherReceiver" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="Organization" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="Department" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="Position" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="ReceiveType" type="irecetns:ReceiveType" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LetterNo" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LetterDateTime" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:dateTime">
                            <xs:attribute name="ShowAs" type="irecetns:DateType" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
<xs:element name="RelatedLetters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="RelatedLetter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:all>
                                    <xs:element name="RelationType" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="RelatedLetterNo" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                                </xs:extension>
                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="RelatedLetterDateTime" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:simpleContent>
                                                <xs:extension base="xs:dateTime">
                                                    <xs:attribute name="ShowAs" type="irecetns:DateType" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                                </xs:extension>
                                            </xs:simpleContent>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <xs:element name="RelatedLetterSender" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Organization" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Department" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Position" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:all>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="Subject" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                        </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Priority" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Classification" nillable="false" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="Code" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Keywords" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Keyword" nillable="false" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

 <xs:element name="Origins" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Origin" nillable="false" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
                                        <xs:attribute name="ContentType" type="irecetns:FileType" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="Extension" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

<xs:element name="Attachments" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Attachment" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:base64Binary">
                                        <xs:attribute name="ContentType" type="xs:string" use="required" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="Extension" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:attribute name="Description" type="xs:string" use="optional" form="unqualified"/>
                                        <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:any   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax" namespace="##any"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="FileType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="image/jpeg"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="image/tiff"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="image/gif"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="image/png"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="application/msword"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="application/pdf"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="text/plain"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="DateType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="gregorian"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Ahmadi"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="hijri"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:simpleType name="ReceiveType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Origin"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Copy"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Refer"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

what is correct XSD file ?

Answer (score 3):

You've got an optional Attachments element, followed by an xs:any which also permits an Attachments element. So if the parser encounters an Attachments element, it doesn't know whether to validate it against your Attachments declaration or against the wildcard.

This rule disappears in XSD 1.1: if the input can match either a specific element declaration or a wildcard, it automatically chooses the specific element declaration.

In XSD 1.0 the usual solution is to set up the wildcard so it only allows names in a different namespace.